# Can Entity Framework be configured to load a collection property where there is no database relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I set a collection property on an EF6 entity class, which I wish to contain a set of reference data from the database, is it possible to configure EF to load this automatically, given that there is no relationship between the two database tables? I'll illustrate with the example of a doctor's appointment system:

```
[Table]
public class Doctor 
{
    public Collection<Slot> AppointmentTimes { get; set; }
}

[Table]
public class Slot
{
    [Column]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Where the Appointment Times are the same for every Doctor. The current solution is what I consider to be a hacky method in the DbContext:

```
public Doctor FindDoctor(int id)
{
     var doctor = this.Doctors.Find(id);

     // I would rather have EF do this for me in the above Find() call
     if (doctor != null)
     {                
         foreach (var slot in this.Slots.ToList())
         {
            doctor.AppointmentTimes.Add(slot);
         }
     }

    return doctor;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to declare a relationship between the two entities when there is clearly a relationship between them?

Comment: These entities don't have a relationship in the database, so it isn't appropriate to give them one in the EF models.  This relationship should exist in higher layers of the application.

Comment: OK you have Doctor & Slots, so far so good. These are totally unrelated and you can only load them together as separate objects. You can use one select (cross join) but that doesn't help you much.

My question is, is your model fully mature?  How are you going use these slots?  Say you want to make an appointment which would include a doctor and a slot, well then you have a relation.

I think you need to work more on your model and discover better the actual relations.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can. open your EDMX, create a new relationship (edmx mapped relation ship and not DB relationship) and save it.

I'm talking about DB first approach

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing here is an Independent Association is Entity Framework https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj713564.aspx

```
var doctor = context.Doctors.First(c=>c.Id == id); 
context.Entry(doctor ).Reference(c => c.AppointmentTimes ).Load();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but these expect a database relationship, i.e. it errors with invalid column names. I know it's a little strange that there is no direct relationship, with the slots always being the same I just didn't want to duplicate them. I'm starting to think they should be defined somewhere else, e.g. config.